# How do I target all the inner class with it's parent's unique_id for each element

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a document article with a unique id and inside it is a section with only a class.

```
<article id="unique_id">
  <header>
    <h1>Article Header</h1>
  </header>
  <p>Article with unique id unique_id</p>
  <section class="section" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Section with uniform class .section</p>
  </section>
</article>
```

How do I target all the section class with it's parent's unique_id for each article, something like ".section#unique_id" and put it in a variable that javascript functions can process.

I only want to target the section element but will have a unique reference based on it's parent id, so I can save them to a localstorage upon changing the content of each section.

Also I don't know the unique_id, I'm only targeting the section class with it's parent's unique_id as a reference, without any knowledge of the parent's specific unique_id.

I tried `document.getElementsByClassName('footer').parentElement();` but cause an error.

Much better if you can provide a neutral solution with only the defaults and not relying on jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].parentNode;
```

It is a property, not a method :)

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` if your browser supports it.